# How can i Serialized a additional property of an object inhert by Collectionbase?

Tags: c#

I have two class like below, I want to serialized the object student to a.xml file.I could create the xml file but could not with the 'ClassName' property.

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : System.Collections.CollectionBase, IEnumerable<Person>
{

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    public void Add(Person person) 
    {
        List.Add(person);
    }

    public Person this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (Person)List[index];
        }
    }

    #region IEnumerable<Person> 成员

    public new IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator() 
    {
        foreach (Person transducer in List)
        yield return transducer;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I got the xml content like this, and no ClassName field

```
Student student = new Student();
student.Add(new Person(){ FirstName = "bill", LastName = "gates" });
student.Add(new Person(){ FirstName = "bill", LastName = "gates" });
student.ClassName = "AAA";
XmlSerializer x2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student));
x2.Serialize(File.Create("ab.xml"), student);
```

How can I get the Property???

Comment: you XML file is not generating *ClassName* ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the default serialization over everything that implements `IList`. It just enumerates the contents, not the properties.

A solution for this is to not implement the `CollectionBase` in your serialized class, but to create a property that does:

```
public class Student
{
    List<Person> Items { get; set; }
}
```